# Check if input is zero, set to empty in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have an input and its type is a number. I need if I remove number from the input it will show empty not a zero.

[image]

after removing 'one'

[image]

my input code

```
   <CInput
                    min="0"
                    max={senddata?.menuItemConfigs[indexID]?.maxSelectionCount}
                    name="max"
                    type="number"
                    placeholder="Maximum say"
                    disabled={!ROLECONTROL("ROLE_MEALPER_ADMIN")}
                    value={
                      senddata?.menuItemConfigs[indexID]
                        ?.maxSelectionCountForEachOption
                    }
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      const data = { ...senddata };
                      if (
                        senddata?.menuItemConfigs[indexID]?.maxSelectionCount >=
                        e.target.value
                      ) {
                        senddata.menuItemConfigs[
                          indexID
                        ].maxSelectionCountForEachOption = Number(
                          e.target.value
                        );
                      }
                      setsenddata(data);
                    }}
                  />
```

I tried this code but logically it was not true, but I checked it anyway

```
   if (e.target.value === 0) {
               senddata.menuItemConfigs[indexID].maxSelectionCountForEachOption = "";
   }
```

I use React

Answer (score 0):

No matter of the React but the JavaScript and HTML itself has a default behavior of defaut zero iput inside the number HTML element.

As you can see the type="number" input is a bit different and has arrows from the right.

If you realy like to remove the default 0 value inside it you can for example remove the type="number". Then again assign type="number" when value comes again.

Then you are going to have the problem that the arrows will dissapear when the field is not of type="number".

Then if you would like at a same time to have a empty input and an arrows from the right you should consider some custom elements which will appear when the input is type="number" and has it's own. And appear again when input is not type="number"

As an example you can follow something like that if you would like to have arrows and a no input at a same time:

```
.d-flex {
    display: flex;
}

.flex-column {
    flex-direction: column;
}

<div class="d-flex">
    <CInput>...</CInput>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column">
        <button>ARROW UP</button>
        <button>ARROW DOWN</button>
    </div>
</div>
```